# How to remove the shadow

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, shadow

I am using [this lib](https://github.com/tosslife/FoldingTabBar.Android) and when I open the menu it makes the shadow like [image: this] i am using blur in the background. And loading the songs from the memory(`in the main thread`). The shadow appears some times. [image: this is what it look withiot shadow]. I dont know why it is happening .In the following layout the background is transparent but the following menu is strong color. what can i do to fix this .I made the images in multiple size also ex hdpi , xhdpi etc. what is the mistake i am doing . The shadow appears when I open and close the menu.
the xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="beatbox.Fragment.Songs">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp">

        <com.github.florent37.arclayout.ArcLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="180"
            app:arc_cropDirection="cropInside"
            app:arc_height="40dp"
            app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#7c2c3940" />

        </com.github.florent37.arclayout.ArcLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/song_listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="48dp"
                android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:overScrollMode="never" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="140dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/total_songs"
                android:textSize="26sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/edittextview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <com.github.stephenvinouze.shapeview.shapes.HalfCircleEdgeShapeView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16.5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:shapeColor="@color/colorAccent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close_edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear_white_48dp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/close_edittext"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/close_edittext"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </com.github.stephenvinouze.shapeview.shapes.HalfCircleEdgeShapeView>

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <com.srx.widget.TabBarView
        android:id="@+id/tabBarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:elevation="0dp" >

    </com.srx.widget.TabBarView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know the solution but I can say nice layout.

Comment: add your xml related part so people can help you

Comment: Try to set android:elevation="0dp", looks like shadow created by os.

Comment: @Kaushal28 thx bro its available in play store now.

Comment: @AtefHares plz check the update question and android:elevation="0dp" is not working.

Comment: what is the name?

Comment: @Kaushal28 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=beatbox.neelay.beatbox this is the app